# Not able to debug app with device using Apple Enterprise Account

Tags: ios

I am trying to debug my application using certificates & provision profile generated by an Enterprise account with my device but I am not able to do so.

Comment: Add some screenshots/errors please

Comment: please explain briefly what types of error you have got?

Comment: Is it a development or distribution provisioning profile?